# HTML Email - 2 Column Layout Issue in Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, responsive

I am trying to create a responsive 2 column HTML email.

At full width (i.e. on desktop) the design looks abit like a 4 panel window, so there is an image top left, a paragraph top right, then a paragraph bottom left, and another image bottom right.

When hitting ther 600px break point, they should all stack on top of eachother. They do this fine in the browser, (Chrome, Firefox and IE) however in Outlook the design goes completely weird.

I have tried various IE kits etc. but nothing seems to work.

If someone could take a look at my code and offer some assistance on how to get the columns to stack properly in Outlook, that would be really appreciated.

The 4 panel Window Panes I mention are commented as Image 1, Text 1, Image 2 and Text 2, this is where I am having the issue, the rest of the code I can deal with.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <style type="text/css">

            body { 
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 600PX) {

                .responsive-table {
                    width: 100% !important;
                    padding: 10px 5%; 
                }

                .responsive-table2 {
                    width: 100% !important;
                }

                .responsive-image {
                    width: 100% !important;
                }

            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>


        <!-- FULL WIDTH CONTAINER --> 
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0px">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">

                    <!-- 600px CONTAINER --> 
                    <table width="600px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0px" class="responsive-table">
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="gold" align="center" style="font-size: 50px; padding: 20px;">
                                HEADER
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="yellow" align="center" style="font-size: 20px; padding: 5px;">
                                NAV BAR
                             </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue" align="center" style="font-size: 50px; padding: 20px;">
                                HEADLINE
                             </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                                <!-- Image 1 -->
                                <table width="300px" height="450px" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="responsive-table2">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <img src="http://cdn.proco.com/public/images/proco/6.jpg" width="300" height="450" class="responsive-image" style="vertical-align: middle;"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                               <!-- Text 1 -->
                               <table width="300px" height="450px" align="right" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="responsive-table2">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="#111" style="padding: 15px; color: white;">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                <!-- Image 2 -->
                                <table width="300px" height="450px" align="right" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="responsive-table2">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <img src="http://cdn.proco.com/public/images/proco/6.jpg" width="300" height="450" class="responsive-image" style="vertical-align: middle;"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                <!-- Text 2 -->
                               <table width="300px" height="450px" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="responsive-table2">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="#111" style="padding: 15px; color: white;">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>    



                            </td>
                         </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="gold" align="center" style="font-size: 50px; padding: 20px;">
                                FOOTER
                             </td>
                         </tr>


                    </table>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try removing the inline styles `width="300px" height="450px"` etc and adding it directly into the `<style>` tag?

Comment: If you just use the HTML patterns of this github repo you should be able to get a good looking HTML mail even in outlook: https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus